# Add toolbar on datagridview in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, custom-controls, toolbox

I created a custom control that inherits a datagridview and add some custom properties. I just add a toolbar control docked on top of it so it can have functionalities like add row, delete row etc. but it displays like this image below:

[image]

as you can see the columnheader was under the toolbox control...I just want them not to overlap each other...please help.

**EDIT**

I just insert a custom property like this one:

```
Dim _Toolbox_ As Toolstrip
Dim _ShowToolbar As Boolean

Public Property ShowToolbar() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _ShowToolbar
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _ShowToolbar = value
        If value = True Then
            _Toolbox_ = New Toolstrip
            MyBase.Controls.Add(_Toolbox_)
            _Toolbox_.Dock = Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top
            _Toolbox_.Visible = True
        Else
            MyBase.Controls.Remove(_Toolbox_)
            _Toolbox_ = Nothing
        End If
    End Set
```

End Property

Comment: I would be more than glad to help you if you showed some code. This would help me understand what you are trying to accomplish. Are you custom drawing the control using inheritance or how are you doing this?

Comment: Yes I am inheriting the datagridview object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `Toolstrip` is a control inside your `DataGridView`, and as such its location origin (0,0) is the top left corner of the `DataGridView`.

In this instance you might be better off creating a [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/c316f119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that allows you to place your `Toolstrip` above your `DataGridView`.  You would expose both of them as properties so that you can still access the controls' own properties and methods, and add a property to turn display of the `Toolstrip` on or off, and set the position of the `DataGridView` appropriately:

```
Dim _ShowToolbar As Boolean
Dim _Toolbox As Toolstrip

Public Property ShowToolbar() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _ShowToolbar
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _ShowToolbar = value
        If value Then
            If _Toolbox Is Nothing Then
                _Toolbox = New Toolstrip()
                Me.Controls.Add(_Toolbox)
            End If

            _Toolbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
            _DataGridView.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0,_Toolbox.Size.Height)
            _Toolbox.Visible = True
        Else
            _Toolbox.Visible = False
            _DataGridView.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0,0)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

All of that is from brain compiler, so there might be errors in there, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to apply your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Use split panel, then insert your toolbar into panel 1 and datagridview into panel 2.